# Regex with negative lookahead, spanning multiple lines

Tags: regex

I am having troubles getting the proper regex for my current testcase.

Example testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <foo_file.h>

int myint = atoi(foostring1);

float myfloat = atof(foostring2);

int myint2 = atoi(foostring3);
```

Use case:

1. string contains atof
   and
2. string doesnt contain the string stdlib.h
3. Groups dont matter.  I just want to know if the string exists or not.

With the regex

```
(?=^#include <stdlib.h>).*atof
```

I can find if the file contains stdlib header and atof.  Works great.  However
I cant seem to get a negative look forward regex like

```
(?!(?=.*^#include <stdlib.h>)).*(atoi)
```

I have tried many hours of different iterations of the above regex line but
cant get it to work.

Assume the IDE's regex engine I am using allows matching across the new/line
return characters and allows me to pick what regex parser/engine I want to
use (but I normally use perl's)

Comment: What is the *negative look forward * regex supposed to yield?

Comment: Try adding `\A` to the start of your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your match can start anywhere in the string. In particular, you are finding a match *after*  the `#include stdlib.h`. The lookahead does then not find any further `stdlib.h` and the match succeeds. Many regex flavors provide `\A` to match the beginning of the string (and only there) regardless of the multiline mode. So to force the lookahead to look through the entire string, do:

```
\A(?!.*^#include <stdlib[.]h>).*(atoi)
```

Note that you don't need to nest another lookahead inside.

Also note that this will fail even if the `#include` is *after* `atoi`. If this is not desired, there are basically two solutions:

If you can pick .NET's regex flavor, you can turn this into a lookbehind:

```
(?<!^#include <stdlib[.]h>.*)atoi
```

Other flavors will not allow this, because they require lookbehinds to be of a fixed width.

In these cases, you will have to check at every position between the beginning of the string and `atoi`, that it doesn't mark the start of the `include`:

```
\A(?:(?!^#include <stdlib[.]h>).)*(atoi)
```

So the `(?:...)` group groups an arbitrary character together with a lookahead for that specific position, and the entire thing is repeated.

Comment: Your regex doesnt match my usecase.  I ran all the regex you listed through regexbuddy with no successes for my above listed test data.

Comment: @user1536029 are you using both the `m` and `s` modifier? The first and third work perfectly fine on http://regex101.com/ for instance (which uses PCRE).

Comment: I just tried my above test case on regex101.com.  I copy the first and 3rd regex to the "Your regular expression" and it doesnt work. Try changing "#include <stdlib.h>" to "#include <stdli.h>".  This is the test case that I need to succeed.  atoi was used and "#include <stdlib.h>" was not included above the use of atoi.

Comment: @user1536029 again, have you added `ms` into the "optional flags" field?

Comment: m.buettner: Thanks.  Confirmed.  I had "m s" modifiers in the optional flags box.  It must be "ms".  So "\A(?:(?!^#include <stdlib[.]h>).)*(atoi)" + "ms" do indeed work.  I also verified with regexbudy, powergrep and all is working good now.  Thanks.